# How to correctly iterate through a search result in MongoDB-Shell?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, iterator

I have a MongoDB table containing 500 documents:

```
db.x.find().count()
```

Now I'd like to iterate over the all entries. Unfortunately the following code only gives `49`, instead of `500`:

```
a=0; for (s in db.x.find()) { a++; }; print(a);
```

I already increased the Number of results to `1000`:

```
DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 1000
```

But that did not help.

Comment: try db.x.find().forEach(function(item) {...})

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you use the [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement in java script, it iterates the `enumerable` properties of an `Object`.

`db.x.find()`  returns you a [cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/#read-operations-cursors) Object. 
Some of the `enumerable` properties of the `Cursor` are as below:

```
_mongo
_db
_collection
_ns
_query
_fields
_limit
_skip
_batchSize
_options
_cursor
_numReturned
_special help clone
_ensureSpecial
hasNext
map
forEach
```

In total there are `49` such properties of a `Cursor`. That is why you always get 49 as a result irrespective of whether you iterate an empty collection or a collection with more than 1000 records. You are iterating these properties and not the results in the cursor.

If you notice these enumerable properties, you can find `hasNext`, `map`, `forEach` functions as `properties` of the cursor. So you need to make use of these properties to iterate the cursor.

To [iterate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/) the results in a Cursor:

```
var myCursor = db.x.find();

while (myCursor.hasNext()) {
   print(tojson(myCursor.next()));
}
```

or,

```
db.x.find().forEach(function(i){

})
```

or,

```
db.x.find().map(function(i){
...
})
```

the first being the preferred and documented way.

Comment: Why the downvote? Comment so that the answer can be improved.

Comment: Your answer was perfect for me. My question also received 3 downvotes without a comment,...

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I wanted to use the old school `For-loop`, not `forEach`.

All works as expected for me if we simply add `.toArray()` at the end of the query:

```js
const items = db.getCollection(xxx)
    .find({ ... })
    .toArray(); // The Magic (!)

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log(items[i]);
}
```